# Find Min Values Of $P=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}+\frac{4}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given $x,y,z>0$ and $y+z=x(y^2+z^2)$

Find Min Values Of

$P=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}+\frac{4}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)}$

Could Someone give me an idea ?

Comment: you can try the Lagrange Multiplier Method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $y+z=2t\implies y^2+z^2\ge 2t^2 \implies xt\le 1$

$P\ge \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\dfrac{2}{(1+y)}\dfrac{1}{(1+z)}+\dfrac{4}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)}=\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\dfrac{2}{(1+y)(1+z)}(1+\dfrac{2}{(1+x)})\ge \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\dfrac{2*4}{(1+y+1+z)^2}(1+\dfrac{2}{(1+x)})={(1+x)^2}+\dfrac{2}{(1+t)^2}(1+\dfrac{2}{(1+x)})\ge {(1+x)^2}+\dfrac{2x^2}{(1+x)^2}(1+\dfrac{2}{(1+x)})=f(x) $

note all "=" above will hold when $y=z$,so you can find min of $f(x)$ and $P$

Answer (score 2):

by the Lagrange Multiplier Method we get
$$P\geq \frac{91}{108}$$ the equal sign holds if $$x=\frac{1}{5},y=z=5$$